# Is a group of letters a sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, letters-of-the-alphabet

Is a group of letters a sentence?

I am wondering if a group of a bunch of letters,
Is a Sentence?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A random group of letters *might* spell a sentence, just as a random group of bricks *might* constitute a house; but both are very unlikely.

What exactly a "sentence" is is controversial and will depend largely on the prejudices of the person talking about it; but I don't think anybody would consider a sentence to be composed either of letters or of the sounds which the letters represent. For most people who use the term a sentence is composed of what we may for simplicity's sake call "words"; those words must be meaningful in a particular language, they must be ordered according to the morphological and syntactical rules of that language, and their ordering must exhibit a particular structure, complexity and coherent meaning demanded by the currently operative definition of "sentence".

In practice, a "sentence" is any portion of a written utterance which lies between two stops. The term is of very little use for anything except passing examinations by conforming your writing to your teacher's understanding of what a sentence is.

Comment: *"'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves. Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:"*  Still a sentence  :)

Comment: @Andrew Well, that full stop isn't in Carrol's original, and the colon's a suspension, not a stop. :)